# Generic Inheritance and Calling GetMethod().getReturnType()

Tags: java, generics, reflection

In my current project, I have classes which are modeled like the following. At some point, a method like `getReturnTypeForGetId()` is called on classes `A` and `B`. Calling the method with `A` returns `Integer` as expected, but `B` returns `Serializable`.

What am I missing here? Am I getting bitten by some heinous erasure thing, or am I just missing out on some sort of generic context-clobbering?

**EDIT:** Adding an over-ridden `getId()` method to `B` fixes the problem, but I would still like to understand what I am running into.

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class WeirdTester {
    static interface Identifiable<T extends Serializable> {
        T getId();
        void setId(final T id);
    }

    static abstract class BaseEntity<T extends Serializable> implements Identifiable<T> {
        private T id;
        public T getId() { return id; }
        public void setId(final T id) { this.id = id; }
    }

    static class A implements Identifiable<Integer> {
        private Integer id;
        public Integer getId() { return id; }
        public void setId(final Integer id) { this.id = id; }
    }

    static class B extends BaseEntity<Integer> {}

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private static <T extends Serializable, Q extends Identifiable<T>> Class<T> getReturnTypeForGetId(
            final Class<Q> clazz) throws Exception {
        return (Class<T>) clazz.getMethod("getId", (Class[])null).getReturnType();
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(getReturnTypeForGetId(A.class));
        // CONSOLE: "class java.lang.Integer"
        System.out.println(getReturnTypeForGetId(B.class));
        // CONSOLE: "interface java.io.Serializable"
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to achieve what you're trying to with super type tokens? http://gafter.blogspot.com/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple `getId` methods in the compiled `A` class. You get a bridge method for the covariant return type (a "fiction" of the language not reflected in the virtual machine). The specification for `Class.getMethod` says that it will return the method with the most specific return type (assuming that exists). It does this for `A`, but for `B` the method is not overridden so javac avoids synthesizing an unnecessary bridge method.

In fact, for this example all the information is still there in the class files.  (Earlier I said it wasn't [erased](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.6). That's not true, but erasure doesn't mean that it isn't there!) The generic information is however a little tricky to extract (it'll be in `Identifiable.class.getGenericReturnType()`, `Identifiable.class.getTypeParameters()`,  `BaseEntity.class.getGenericInterfaces`, `BaseEntity.class.getTypeParameters()` and `B.getGenericSuperclass` (I think!)).

Use `javap` to see exactly what you have in the class files.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your answer. For me it is, that if you add setId2(final Serializable id) into BaseEntity, id field may contain any Serializable not just Integer, therefore if getId() is not overridden in B (and so enforced to only return Integer) any Serializable may come out of it. Checking that no method may set id field to anything other than Integer is not compiler's/JVM's job.

Comment: To implement `setId2` so that it actually works, `this.id = (T)id;`, would give a warning (which should be heeded!!). `getId` on an instance of `B` would then throw a `ClassCastException` from the caller (I think).

Comment: (I think...incorrectly.) A bug that was corrected early on was that javac will cast to the correct overload. So if `T` was `char[]` that would CCE.

Comment: I miss some kind of 'View history' kind of button in SO. Questions and resulting answers may get a bit confusing with all the editing done in realtime while people rush to answer.

Answer (score 2):

In class A you override getId to return Integer.

In class B you don't override getId, so the getId method in B is the one from BaseEntity. Because of erasure, that one returns Serializable.

Comment: wrong. This has nothing to do with erasure. The BaseEntity.id may contain any Serializable. (inference of that no method does set it to any other Serializable is way above what compiler does). If B does not override getId(), where it would be enforced that getId() only returns Integer, any Serializable may come out of getId()

Comment: @MarianP: I think you may want to re-read about what "type erasure" means, as it *does* occur in the mentioned case.

Comment: @MarianP You say "wrong", but the rest of your comment is speculation. Have you actually tried decompiling the code to see what javac does? I have. The enforcement of generics is done through a combination of static proofs (that are only valid when there are no unchecked casts) and runtime casts.

Comment: @LaurenceGonsalves I can't see how any of what I wrote is a speculation as I only follow basic Java rules. I won't try to reason if playing with compiled code is the right reasoning but let's leave it. Thinking about your answer a bit I find you reasoning fine, it is just concise. I downvoted it after seeing the 'erasure', there is another clearly wrong answer, which I saw first, dealing with erasure here. I would not use the word erasure because nothing significant is erased in this case and it's not erasure that makes it use Serializable, but I admit my downvote was hasty and I take it back.

Comment: @LaurenceGonsalves could you edit some char in your answer so that I can cancel my downvote?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is indeed type erasure. Remember that generics are only a trick, hints in the non-compiled Java code. The compiler removes everything that has to do with them to produce bytecode. So when you use reflection on the getId method, you only get the raw type.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html

But if you ask for the class of an actual object returned by this method (B.getId), without using reflection, due to the way it's constructed, you'll get an Integer.

Comment: wrong. the BaseEntity.id may contain any Serializable. (inference of that no method does set it to any other Serializable is way above what compiler does). If B does not override getId(), where it would be enforced that getId() only returns Integer, any Serializable may come out of getId()

Answer (score 1):

*id* in BaseEntity is *private* and '*Serializable* or extending *Serializable*'.

Class B (which extends BaseEntity) does not know anything about this field. If it defined its own *id* and did not override getId()/setId(...) those two methods would continue using the BaseEntity.id

If you add this method in the BaseEntity:

```
public void setId2(final Serializable id) {
        this.id = (T) id;
}
```

it lets you set the BaseEntity.id to any Serializable.

In following test you may then set the id field to e.g. a *Float* value and everything compiles and non-changed *getId()* comfortably returns the Float value.

```
B b = new B();
b.setId2(2.1F);
System.out.println( b.getId() ); //prints out 2.1
```

Therefore, if you do what you do and ask 'What is the return type of B.getId() method', then unless you override getId() method in B class (which would force it to use the Integer function type and return Integer for sure. Note that BaseEntity.id would not even be visible to B then!) the reflection's answer is not Integer but a generic Serializable. Because any Serializable may come out of the getId() method really.

Answer (score -1):

Java allows so called "narrowing" of return values' types. That's why your example works at all:

`Serializable getId()`

can be overridden with any serializable return type, like

`Integer getId()`, as `Integer` implements `Serializable`, so the narrowing is allowed in this case.

Because `B` does *not* override `getId()` its `getId()` is the same as the one inherited from `BaseEntity`. The declaration

```
class B extends BaseEntity<Integer>
```

is "type-erased" at compile time to

```
class B extends BaseEntity
```

and, voilà, we receive the observed result.

Comment: you mean covariant returns? it only says that you may use a subtype of return type in overridden method. It has no relation to this question.

Comment: Sorry, but you didn't get the point: For the generic class (and thus for *B*) above, *T getId()* will be compiled to *Serializable getId()*. That's why by reflection the return type *Serializable* is returned.  
In class *A* *Integer getId()* overrides the inherited *Serializable getId()* because *Integer* is serializable. So when compiled, class *A*'s method will return an *Integer*, which is just what reflection tells you at runtime, as the OP observed.

Comment: this is true. you really did not reason all this length in your answer. Edit some char in your answer please so that I can cancel my downvote.